# Background change on hover in webflow

Tags: webflow

Question:

I am creating web page in webflow. I have a parent `div` divided into three child `div`s. I want to change the background image of the parent `div` when I hover over each child `div`, but I don't want to use custom coding within Webflow. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Animation on hover assign them to change BG color or if there is image  on hover animation for intial stage you can hide that image and one hover you can show that image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).